# Is there a name for Python code which is not in a function?

Tags: python

The title pretty much says it.

I am wondering what I should call code that is just sitting in a Python file, not in any function at all.

For some context - in the particular module I am concerned with, there are some functions with definitions that have been defined, but there is also some code sitting at the end that is executed whenever the module is imported. What is this code called?

Comment: Are you not just refering to a script ?

Comment: That must be a script

Comment: "module-level code"?

Comment: It wouldn't have to be a script; one could easily imagine a module consisting of nothing but variable definitions.

Comment: module-level or top-level or module's top-level...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is usually called

`global scope code`,
`module level code` or
`top-level code`

but it doesn't have proper naming convention but programmers would understand what you mean when you use any of these.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your code be triggered only when executed directly, please use `if __name__ == '__main__'` condition:

> `__name__` is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes.
>   A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read from standard
>   input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.
>
> A module can discover whether or not it is running in the main scope
>   by checking its own **name**, which allows a common idiom for
>   conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or
>   with python -m but not when it is imported.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```